# What would be a simple implementation of a collection with non-repeating elements?

Tags: agda

I know that there is an AVL tree in the standard library, but that feels too complex for my purposes. A vanilla function meets most my requirements, except for being able to iterate over the keys.

It is not like I strictly do not know how to make some proposition that for every element in a list there is no duplicate - I did so in Coq once, but I am trying to get a handle on how to bake it into the structure directly and am running into difficulties.

```
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

data UniqueList {a} (A : Set a) : Set a
data NotIn {a} {A : Set a} : A → UniqueList A → Set a

data UniqueList A where
  [] : UniqueList A
  _∷_ : ∀ (x : A) (xs : UniqueList A) → NotIn x xs → UniqueList A

data NotIn {a} {A} where
  done : ∀ (x : A) → NotIn x []
  dive : ∀ (x y : A) (ys : UniqueList A) (prf : NotIn y ys) → NotIn x ys → ¬ x ≡ y → NotIn x ((y ∷ ys) prf)
```

I thought I might try something like this, but it feels awkward. Any advice for how to deal with this?

Comment: I guess I'll go with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679462/is-there-an-element-in-list-datatype-defined-in-the-standard-library/58680751#58680751) unless something better comes up.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that `std-lib` has readmes for various modules. [Here](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Data.AVL.html) is the one for the AVL tree. This does give me some awareness of what is possible with it.

Comment: Thanks! That readme has moved to https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Data.Tree.AVL.html. I only found as follows: go to the top-level README, https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Data.html, search "AVL".